# Live Ads Not displaying in my App in Playstore

Tags: java, android, admob

I'v tested my App in test device, it displayed test Ads and everything worked fine but once my app went to production and when we get it from google playstore the ad is not displaying.It's already 2 days since my app is released.
Please suggest me what i have to do. Will it take more time?

My App comes under designed for families category.
Any app with designed for families category is able to display ads?

Comment: capture logs from device and update in your question

Answer (score 1):

I'v Checked in the admob Report
Till now i'v got 319 Admob network request but only 6 matched requests only 4 impressions that means designed for family category will get very very less ad fills.

For App designed for family category and kids.The only way to yield revenue is either through in-app purchase or through paid apps only.